# How can I use a html link in UIWebView to push a view on to the stack?

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview, hyperlink, viewcontroller

I have a UIWebView containing html-formatted text. In the text some words are links. When clicked on they should push another view on to the stack. How should I write the html link and corresponding objective-c code to make this work?

Comment: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/26/uiwebview-tutorial-link-to-an-ibaction/  OR  http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-override-uiwebview-links-request-action-with-your-own-custom-method/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up delegate for UIWebView, then you can handle link action clicked:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'v tried this solution, but I can't get the shouldStartLoadWithRequest to fire. I'm creating the UIWebView programmatically and adding it to a table cell. In the ViewController.h file I set the delegate like this: 
@interface ViewController:UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
What am I missing in the setup?

Comment: @user1279526, `myWebView.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:** Full UIWebView example to push a view in stack and open another html file in bundle when clicked on html link e.g. `<a href="imprint.html">imprint</a>`

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!     
    var filename:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard filename != nil else {
            fatalError("filename not defined")
        }

        view.backgroundColor =  UIColor.white

        webView.isOpaque = false;
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        //remove file extension first
        filename = filename!.replace(".html", replacement: "")

        let localfilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "html")
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: localfilePath!)
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest)
    }

    ...
}

extension WebViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        //set view title from html document
        let pageTitle = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.title")
        navigationItem.title = pageTitle
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

         if navigationType == .linkClicked,
            let urlStr = request.url?.absoluteString,
            !urlStr.contains("http://"),
            let filename = request.url?.lastPathComponent, //e.g. imprint.html
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebView") as? WebViewController{

            vc.filename = filename

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```